# Fitting Matchmaker X to SRAM Guide T brakes?

Tags: mountain-bike, brakes, shifter, sram

I've got a prebuilt MTB that came with an SRAM NX drivetrain and Guide T brakes and I'm looking at upgrading the drivetrain to higher end parts.
I'm thinking about taking the upgrade opportunity to switch to the Matchmaker X system, the new shifter will definitely be compatible and I can get hold of a clamp like this without an issue:
[image: SRAM Matchmaker clip]

I understand that the new shifter will be attached to the screw thread facing downwards. The SRAM website claims my Guide T brakes are Matchmaker compatible too (https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/db-gde-t-a1) but it doesn't look like it from their picture as its a two bolt clip similar to this image. My brake body has half the clamp molded into it, then the second piece fits on the back.

[image: Brake clip with two bolts]

The Guide R below appears to be attached through Matchmaker, but the body is a completely different shape below. It appears to have a small wedge with a hole for the Matchmaker clip's bolt to fit through

[image: Guide R]

I'm either missing something silly, or are there are multiple versions of Guide T brakes with different body styles that SRAM doesn't make clear on their site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further research shows there are *two* systems, Matchmaker and Matchmaker X. My Guide T brakes allow the use of Matchmaker and the new Eagle Shifters use Matchmaker X. It seems as though all of the other Guide brakes (including the R in the bottom picture above) use Matchmaker X.

I either need to find a Matchmaker clamp adapter like this https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/db-acc-mm-a1 or swap my brakes at the same time.

Comment: Great finding, thank you for coming back to share the answer.  Yet another incompatible standard... its like manufacturers do this intentionally.

Comment: @Criggie yes, and even worse that models in the same range match different standards with similar names :(

Comment: I found this   https://www.chainreactioncycles.com/mobile/avid-matchmaker-mtb-lever-mount-adaptors/rp-prod15889

Comment: @JoeK this question is 9 months old. It's quite possible that item was out of stock at the time.

Comment: @ChrisFletcher "Unavailable in Europe" is different to "temproarily out of stock", so my point is relevant criticism against the accepted answer, as the part is available on the European market *even if stock was low* 9 months ago.

Comment: @JoeK I've updated the above answer (you could have too). But for posterity it said "Unable to find", draw what you will from the temporary or non-temporary implications of those words.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! The Avid Matchmaker part I ordered from Amazon fit exactly with the Guide T brakes. I ended up just using the bolt and the two small metal pieces. I saved the “big” bracket that actually attaches to the brake lever because there was nothing wrong with mine and didn’t feel like removing, installing the new part and adjusting the lever.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question... looks like the Guide T uses the original MatchMaker design from Avid. I found it on Amazon here in the US [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001U6KI78](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001U6KI78). I just ordered one pair to see if it works with my brakes. I'll post later how it went.

Comment: Please do update this!  You also appear to have created 2 different accounts; you should check out the help on [merging your accounts](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).